# Numerically optimize over function space in R

Tags: r, numerical-methods, numerical-integration, numerical-analysis

I want to numerically maximize an expression in R. In order to keep it simple, suppose that the expression I want to maximize is

[\int_0^1 2x y(x)(y(x) -2)  dx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgCKh.gif)

where

y(x) = \int_0^1 y(x,t) dt

and where I maximize over the set of functions y: [0,1]^2 -> {0,1}.

I want to numerically maximize this expression in R and this is how I thought I'd do it:

1. Discretize the unit square using a matrix
2. Discretize the integrand
3. Calculate the value of the sum
4. Do this for all matrices see which maximizes the value

Since the functions I want to maximize over only take values in {0,1} I thought of using a matrix taking values 0/1 to approximate the function and to then approximate the rest of the integrand on that grid. Here's the code:

```
    Value <- function(grid){
    # The argument grid is the matrix taking values 0 or 1
    # For now, consider a 10-times-10 matrix
    Value <- 2*seq(1/20, 19/20, 1/10) %*% apply(grid, 1, sum)/10
    return(Value)
    }
```

How can I now create a list of all 0/1 matrices in order to then apply the above function to all of them to see which grid, i.e., which approximation of the function y reaches the maximum? Or is there an altogether different and better way to do this numerical optimization?

Comment: I managed to create a list of all the 0/1 matrices, but (not surprisingly) this object is too large very quickly. So I need an altogether different approach. Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your search algorithm which enumerates all possible 2^(10*10) discretised functions is extremely poor. You should better try local optimisation like Nelder-Mead to maximise the function.